# How to upgrade Ubuntu

Tags: upgrade, lubuntu, 10.10

My Ubuntu 10.10 is no longer supported. Some programs like Update Manager will not open. And a bunch of other Ubuntu programs. I was wondering if it would work if I:

1: Got an 8GB USB flash drive

2: Correctly put Ubuntu 14.04.3 on the USB flash drive

3: Plugged the USB flash drive (with Ubuntu on it) in the computer that runs the faulty Ubuntu

4. Installed it and totally get rid of Ubuntu 10.10
5. Ran the new Ubuntu

Would this work? Because I figured that it would because it is just like installing any other Ubuntu.

Today (10-22-15) I will be going out to buy a USB flash drive! Please leave a response if you read this.

Comment: You have 1 option: re-install. Topic will get closed as 10.10 is off topic and this has been answered before.

Comment: That thing that says this question already has an answer, I already tried that and it didn't work. I ran all those commands and still nothing happened. In fact stuff went missing.

Answer (score 1):

the easier way I think is like this:

**1. Launch the Software Updater**
Press the Superkey (Windows key) to launch the Dash and search for Update Manager

**2. Check for updates**
Select the tab called "Updates". Then set the "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version" dropdown menu to "For any new version". Press Alt+F2 and type in "update-manager" (without the quotes) into the command box. The Update Manager should open up and tell you: New distribution release '15.04' is available. Click Upgrade and follow the on-screen instructions.

**3. Install the upgrade**
A message will appear informing you of the availability of the new release. Click Upgrade and follow the on-screen instructions.

I hope this helped you :)

INFO link: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade

Comment: I tried that already. The update manager is one of those programs that refuses to open. Ok. My USB purchase is going to happen.